# Creating a list from generic type in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I have an interface of the form:

```
public interface Tester<K1, V1> {
    ...
}
```

A client will implement this interface, then pass me the .class file for their subclass. I then parse out the K1, V1 from the interface in the following manner:

```
// Assume only Tester<K1, V1> is implemented for now:
Type genericInterface = ClientClass.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0]; 
if(genericInterface instanceof ParameterizedType){
    Type[] genericTypes = ((ParameterizedType) genericInterface).getActualTypeArguments();
    List<?> myList = new ArrayList<genericTypes[1]>(); // THIS DOES NOT WORK!
}
```

I'm trying to instantiate a list based on the generic type declared in their interface. What is the correct way to do this in java? Is this possible? The way that I'm going about it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: generics works with types, not `Type`s ;)

Comment: Can I convert Type to regular types?

Comment: No, since (generic) types are compile time values (type erasure...), and the compilation would be expected at runtime.

Comment: But is't practically impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `List<?> myList` say `List<Object> myList` or even older style: `List myList`. The latter will give you compiler warning, it was the style before generics helped. I cannot fully understand what you want to do though. Do you basically try to determine the type of the generic at runtime?
Generics were introduced so you'd be able to get compile type error checks. Unless there's a really good reason, try to avoid generics (I can only think of that if you build some caching framework, where you really have to handle everything, I've seen that). Try to find the most common denominator base class among those objects what you'll try to handle/store.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I needed to always declare a type. I guess I'll use the List myList way. I know its bad style. And you're right, we are designing a framework and need to accept any type that the client passes to us... I mean, we do know that each type extends Serializable. Would this help?

Comment: @de1337ed: Serializable is more than an Object. When you don't specify anything (really old style) it's called "raw type", the compiler warning will mention that too: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: In other words: Yes, use `Serializable`, or even richer base class if you can. At least you'll prevent anything to get into your data structures which are not Serializable. Most MemCache techniques serialize the content to the out-of-GC memory. This adds overhead, but a common solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your case this **is** possible to do. However, the way you create the ArrayList is illegal, syntactically, since the generic type argument must be known in compile time. Use `new ArrayList<Object>` instead (both in constructor call and declaration).

Comment: If I were to now pass this ArrayList into a client method, the method would then have to cast it to the correct type V1 right? The input for the client method would look something like: public void method(List<V1> v1List)...

Comment: @de1337ed: a cast will work, but will produce a warning, which means that the responsibility for type safety is on you once you do this unsafe cast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using a dynamic value, such as genericTypes[1] in your example, is possible in Java. Generics in Java are basically syntactic sugar which is applied at compile time. The type information is, for the most part, erased at runtime. Some additional information is available in the Java tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: It is possible using raw types or <Object>, see my answer. I agree with your second sentence though.

Comment: I meant that use of a dynamic value in the generic type specifier was impossible, edited my answer to make that clearer. Since the original question said "I'm trying to instantiate a list based on the generic type declared in their interface. What is the correct way to do this in java?" I assumed that they did not want to use the more general <Object> type.